# Why does the program never move past open()?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am using multithreading to calculate the individual checksums of all files in a directory, and I then compute the total of all of the checksums (so the sum of checksums). (Yes, if this concept sounds familiar, I did post a question about using pthread_create before, but I assure you that this is not a duplicate.)

I have code that computes the checksum of one file given `argv[1]`. In that program, the checksum is computed correctly.

However, now I am implementing multiple file checksum computations using multithreading and the individual checksums are never printed. I have debugged and stared for hours yet I am still confused as to why the individual checksums are never printed so why I cannot get pass the line: 
`handle = open(filenames[b], O_RDONLY);` .

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (1<<16)

void cleanup();
void get_filenames();
void* get_checksum();

char **filenames;
int file_cnt;
DIR *dir;

int handle;
unsigned char* ptr;
int length;
int count;
unsigned char* buffer;
int* sum;
unsigned int total = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        int i;
        pthread_t* file;

        atexit(cleanup);
        get_filenames();

        printf("There are %d files:\n", file_cnt);

        file = calloc(file_cnt, sizeof(pthread_t));
        sum = calloc(file_cnt, sizeof(int));
        for(i=0; i<file_cnt; i++){

                printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);

                pthread_create(&(file[i]), NULL, get_checksum, (void*)i);
        }
                for(i=0; i<file_cnt; i++){
                        total += sum[i];
                }
                printf("total is: %u\n", total);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void* get_checksum(void* a){

    unsigned int checksum;
        int b = (int)a;

        printf("b=%d\n", b);

        handle = open(filenames[b], O_RDONLY);

         printf("handle=%d\n", handle);

        if( handle == -1 ){
                  printf( "Can't open file: %s\n", filenames[b]);
                  exit(1);
        }

        buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
        if( buffer == NULL ){
                printf( "Can't get enough memory\n" );
                exit(1);
        }
        checksum = 0;

        printf("length1=%d\n", length);
                 do{
                        length = read(handle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            printf("length=%d\n", length);
                         if(length == -1){
                                printf( "Error reading file: %s\n", filenames[b]);
                exit(1);
                              }

                        ptr = buffer;
                        count = length;

                        while( count-- ){
                                checksum = checksum + (unsigned int)( *ptr++ );
                                sum[b] = checksum;
                        }
                }while(length);
                    printf("Checksum = %d\n", checksum);
}

void cleanup() {

        if(filenames && file_cnt > 0) {
                while(file_cnt-- > 0) {
                        if(filenames[file_cnt]) {
                                free(filenames[file_cnt]);
                        }
                }
                free(filenames);
        }

        if(dir) {
                closedir(dir);
        }

        return;
}


void get_filenames() {

        struct dirent *dir_entry;

        if((dir = opendir(".")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open the directory entry for reading\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        errno = 0;
        file_cnt = 0;
        while((dir_entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                char **new_filenames = filenames;
                static int realative_dirs = 0;

                if(realative_dirs < 2 &&
                   (strcmp(".", dir_entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..", dir_entry->d_name) == 0)
                  ) {
                        realative_dirs++;
                        continue;
                }

                new_filenames = (char **)realloc(filenames, sizeof(char **) * (file_cnt + 1));
                if(new_filenames == NULL) {
                        free(filenames[file_cnt]);
                        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate reference for filename[%d]\n", file_cnt);
                        exit(1);
                }

                filenames = new_filenames;
                filenames[file_cnt] = (char *)calloc(strlen(dir_entry->d_name) + 1, sizeof(char));
                if(filenames[file_cnt] == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for filename[%d]'s string: \"%s\"\n",
                                file_cnt, dir_entry->d_name);
                        exit(1);
                }

                strcpy(filenames[file_cnt], dir_entry->d_name);
                file_cnt++;
        }

        if(errno != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "An error occured getting the filenam list\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        return;
}
```

My output:

```
    There are 7 files:
    test.c
    a.out
    test.c.save
    test2.c
    b=2
    test3.c
    checksum.c
    b=0
    b=1
    b=3
    checksum1.c
    b=5
    total is: 0
```

As you can see from the output, I cannot print the value of `handle` or anything past `handle = open(filenames[b], O_RDONLY);`. I am new to programming so any suggestions as to why I cannot move past that line are greatly appreciated. (Please note that I am running Linux through a virtual machine so the target is Linux)

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )    The posted code is a LONG ways from cleanly compiling.  Why try to run the code when it does not cleanly compile?

Comment: The function: `read()` is not prototyped,  because the code is missing the appropriate header.   Suggest inserting the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: in C, the returned type from the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) has type `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, makes understanding, debugging, and maintenance much more difficult.  Suggest removing the casting of the returned values from the memory allocation functions

Comment: the array `filenames[]` contains multiple pointers to allocated memory.  a single call to `free()` will not free all those pointers.  Strongly suggest using a loop to free the pointers then pass `filename` to `free()`

Comment: the function `main()` parameters are not used, this causes the compiler to raise two warning messages.  Suggest changing the main() signature to `int main( void )`

Comment: the function `calloc()` is expecting both its' parameters to have type of `size_t`, however, the variable `file_cnt` has type `int`.  suggest changing the declaration of `file_cnt` to: `size_t file_cnt;`

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding by us humans: when indenting code, NEVER use tabs because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for several indent levels across the page

Comment: in the code block beginning with: `if( handle == -1 )` 1) the error message should be passed via stderr, not stdout.  2) rather than assuming the cause of the problem, use `perror( "open failed" );`   which will also output the system error message that indicates why the OS thinks the 'open()` failed. --or-- `fprintf( stderr, ""Can't open file: %s due to: %s\n", filenames[b], strerror( errno ));

Comment: the first parameter to the function: `pthread_create()` is a pointer to where to save the `thread id` not a `file`.  for ease of understanding, Names of variables should be meaningful and indicate contents or usage (or better both).

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans, separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank lline.

Comment: the function: `get_checksum()` signature says the function will return a `void*` but there is no `return &x;` kind of statement in the function, especially at the end of the function

Comment: regarding this line: `pthread_create(&(file[i]), NULL, get_checksum, (void*)i);` the last parameter should be: `(void*)&i`   then in function: `get_checksum()` this line: `int b = (int)a;`  should be: `int b = (int)*a;`  This is especially true on 64 bit architectures where a pointer and a int are not the same size

Comment: the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: in the function: `get_checksum()`, the line: `sum[b] = checksum;`  updates the value in `sum[b]` for every 4 (or on 64 bit architectures) every 8 bytes in the input file.   that is a waste of CPU cycles and clutters the code.  Suggest placing the statement after the outer `while()` loop.

Comment: if the size of the input file is not a multiple of 4 (or 8 in a 64 bit architecture) then the last addition to the check sum will be reading uninitialized bytes from `buffer[]`.   Note: normally a checksum is byte by byte, not sizeof(int) by sizeof(int)

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value into a temporary pointer, then check (!=NULL) that pointer, and if NOT NULL, then save to the target pointer.  Otherwise, the pointer to the previously allocated memory will be lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: after calling `realloc()`, do NOT pass the original pointer to `free()`, because the call to `realloc()` may (or may not because it was able to extend the allocated memory) have already passed the original pointer to `free()`  and calling `free()` on an already free'd pointer will cause a seg fault event.

Comment: in function: `get_filenames()`  in the code block beginning with: `if(new_filenames == NULL)`, this line:  `free(filenames[file_cnt]);` is not correct, because `exit()` will call `cleanup()`.   Cleanup()` has a problem when no memory for a new (or any) file name has been allocated, but the char ** filenames has been allocated.

Comment: if the code exits a thread, the `cleanup()` function will be called, then when the main thread exits, the `cleanup()` function will be called again.  Therefore, the cleanup() function needs to reset any variables, so when it is called again, it does not try to pass anything to `free()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to have other issues, but I'll only address why it seems to be terminating after `open()`.

It's not actually terminating after `open`: You never wait for your threads to be joined. Once you've created the threads, the main thread exits. You need to use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads created via `pthread_create` to terminate.

You seemingly have a few threads which are executed between the first `pthread_create` and when the actual loop (in main) terminates, but that's just conincidental.

Comment: ..or use some other mechanism to prevent inappropriate and unwanted process termination.